# CPack: Ignoring files using regex

Tags: cmake

(apologies: cross-posted from CMake mailing list)

I'm trying to get my head round CMake's regex implementation; I have a folder containing 4 folders and 2 text files as follows:

```
build/  
projectA/  
CMakeLists.txt  
extrafiles/  
README  
temp/
```

One line of CMakeLists.txt is:

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "[^projectA]$")
```

In my source package that is then subsequently generated, `build/`, `projectA/` and `extrafiles` are present, but `temp/` and the 2 text files are not. I'm trying to get to a stage where the regex will ignore everything in the folder except for `projectA/`, `README` and `CMakeLists.txt`, but can't work out at the moment how the regex I've
supplied is giving those results.

I guess what this boils down to is how to match a whole string using regex.  I realise that the docs say `Matches any character(s) not inside the brackets` which is where I guess I'm going wrong...

**Further exploration**

In trying to understand CMake's regex implementation, I thought I'd start from 1st principles and do some easy stuff.

If I do

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES projectA)
```

then the folder `projectA` doesn't appear in my source package (as expected); however, if I do

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES ^projectA$)
```

or

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES ^/projectA/$)
```

then `projectA` **does** appear.  What is it about the `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line) that I'm not understanding?

**Even more**

As probably obvious, `projectA` is not actually the name of my project, but everything above holds true when I physically rename my project folder to `projectA`.  But, when I replace

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES projectA)
```

with

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES <name of my project>)
```

and rename my actual project folder from `projectA` to its actual name, I end up with an **empty** tarball! Argh! I have absolutely **no** idea what strange tricks CMake is playing on me, but I just want to cry.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

**SELF CONTAINED EXAMPLE**

[As requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935748/cpack-ignoring-files-using-regex#comment26289963_17957519) by Fraser, a self contained example showing 2 of the 'features' I've described. However, I do know that I'm running CMake in a slightly non-standard way, in order to keep everything to do with individual builds together, so if there's any proof running CMake in a more standard way eliminates these problems I'd be interested to see them.

**Step 1: creating files**

Create tree:

```
cd ~
mkdir 
cd projectA
mkdir projectA
```

Create C file, and save it as `~/projectA/projectA/helloworld.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("!!!Hello World!!!\n"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    printf("!!!Hello CMake!!!\n"); /* prints !!!Hello CMake!!! */
    return 0;
}
```

create a file that won't need compiling, and save it as `~/projectA/test.sh`:

```
#A non compiled program
echo "Hello world!"
```

create `~/projectA/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (HelloWorld) 

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "$ENV{HOME}/projectAinstall")

add_executable(helloworld projectA/helloworld.c)
install(TARGETS helloworld DESTINATION .)

include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "TGZ")

include(CPack)
```

**Step 2: compiling**

In `~/projectA`, run:

```
chris@chris:~/projectA$ cmake -H. -Bbuild
```

then:

```
make -C build && make -C build package && make -C build package_source
```

this results in 2 tarballs in the `build` folder.  Moving these somewhere else and untarring them shows `helloworld` in the binary tarball (as expected), and *everything* from the `~/projectA/projectA` in the source tarball, including `test.sh` which won't get compiled (which Fraser seemed surprised about)

**Step 3: random tests**

Modifying `CMakeLists.txt` to include

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "projectA")
```

and rerunning the CMake / Make commands above results in an empty source tarball, but with the same binary tarball as above.  I have now realised that changing the directory tree so that the top level directory is `testproject` (and so different to its child folder) *doesn't* result in an empty source tarball, and does only remove the files listed in `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I don't think you can achieve what you're after using `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` (although I'm not certain).  As you rightly noted, CMake's regex handling allows for excluding groups of characters, but I don't think it allows for negating whole patterns.</del> [See updated answer at the end of the edits.]

That being said, I guess you can list all the folders you wish to exclude in your `install` command.  Not as robust as excluding everything except "projectA", but still here's the syntax:

```
install(DIRECTORY .
        DESTINATION the_install_subdir
        REGEX "build|extrafiles|temp+" EXCLUDE)
```

Regarding the empty tarball, I imagine that you maybe have `<name of my project>` both as your project's root dir and as a subdir?  So in your example, if you called your project "projectA", then you'd have "projectA/build", "projectA/projectA", etc.

If so, the regex will work on the full path, and hence *all* files within your project will contain `projectA/` within their paths.

As for the crying... well, I can only advise you to get a grip and pull yourself together!  :-)

---

**Edit:** In response to the comments, here's a quick example of using the [`install`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainstall) command to achieve the goal:

```
install(DIRECTORY projectA
        DESTINATION the_install_subdir)
install(FILES CMakeLists.txt README DESTINATION the_install_subdir)
```

---

**Further Edit:**

OK, your example helps a lot - I had indeed misunderstood what you were doing.  I hadn't picked up that you were actually making 2 different targets ("package" and "package_source").  I had thought you were creating the binary package by doing something like

```
cpack -G DEB
```

and that you were creating the other package by doing

```
cpack -G TGZ
```

These both build the binary package.  My mistake - I should have paid more attention.  Sorry!

As for your specific questions:

**Question 1**

> It seems to me that installing files / directories that aren't compiled but are at the same level as the folder containing all the compiled files (i.e. bin), and then ignoring the bin folder using CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES results in an empty tarball - is this correct?

I take this to mean: "Should doing `set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")` result in an empty tarball?"  The answer is probably not.

Because `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` represents a regex, I'm sure there are cases where the resultant regex *could* match every file in the project, and this would cause an empty tarball.  However I imagine it's fairly unlikely.

If, rather than using the full path to your bin dir via the variable `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` you were to just give the folder name, there would be a much greater chance of an empty tarball.  Say you call your bin dir "build" and have `set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "build")`.  If your project lived in say `~/test_builds/projectA`, then the regex "build" would match every file in the project since each contains "test_builds"; resulting in an empty tarball.

I think this is the crux of issue each time you've generated an empty tarball.  Whatever the regex is trying to achieve, it actually ends up matching and excluding all files.

**Question 2**

> It also seems that files in the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` which aren't 'installed' don't end up in the binary tarball but do end up in the source tarball

Yes, the "package_source" is indeed a different target to the binary package.  It by default contains *all* files in the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`, whereas the "package" target contains only items added via `install` commands.  Here, the term "source files" is probably a slight misnomer since it means all files in the source tree - not just .c, .cc, .cxx, etc.

**Original Question**

I think there's a reasonably safe way to achieve your original aim after all!  If you use [`file(GLOB ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afile) to generate a non-recursive list of all files/folders in your root, then remove those you wish to keep in the source package, you should be able to use the remaining list as the regex value of `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES`:

```
file(GLOB SourceIgnoreFiles "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*")
set(SourceKeepFiles "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/projectA"
                    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt"
                    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/README")
list(REMOVE_ITEM SourceIgnoreFiles ${SourceKeepFiles})
# Escape any '.' characters
string(REPLACE "." "\\\\." SourceIgnoreFiles "${SourceIgnoreFiles}")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "${SourceIgnoreFiles}")
```

Hopefully this should now work for you.  Sorry again for the misdirections.

Comment: 3 comments!: Is it the case that if you ignore the directory that all install commands refer to, CPack will just automatically ignore everything else (hence creating an empty tarball)? I'm not sure I can see the advantage of listing files in an `INSTALL(DIRECTORY ...)` command rather than just in a `set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE FILES ...)`, but I'm sure there is one? The real reason for excluding everything is because one of my colleagues was concerned that people who had spurious files in their own dev folder would end up in the source package erroneously, and I wanted to prevent this

Comment: !) Yes - I believe so.  2) I'd imagined you already had one or more `install` calls in your CMakeLists.txt - that's always how I've used CPack.  I'm not sure what happens if you `include(CPack)` and don't have any `install` calls.  I suppose I'd expect an empty tarball in that case.  3) I agree that my solution isn't as robust as an "exclude everything except" method, but I thought this was the closest to what you were asking.  My preferred technique (I think the safest) is to explicitly list everything to be *included* via `install` calls rather than trying to exclude things.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I made myself very clear! I do have *lots* of `install` calls (as per your example).  It seems to me that installing files / directories that aren't compiled but are at the same level as the folder containing all the compiled files (i.e. bin), and then ignoring the bin folder using `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` results in an empty tarball - is this correct? It also seems that files in the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` which aren't 'installed' don't end up in the binary tarball but *do* end up in the source tarball - there is a separate `CPACK_IGNORE_FILES` which I'm not using

Comment: I wouldn't expect either of those things to happen.  If you could post a self-contained example CMakeLists.txt which demonstrates the behaviour it could possibly help?

Comment: I've added a complete example (along with some waffle) to my question!

Comment: @ChrisW - I've seen your waffle and raised you some wittering (in the form of an updated answer).  Things are clearer now I hope!

Comment: Thanks for all this! I'm slowly starting to get my head around it all... I didn't know about the `-G` flag, will go experimenting with it! Is there any advantage to running `cpack` separately, rather than having everything in 1 file like I have? I like your solution to my original regex problem - very ingenious! :)

Comment: I don't think there are any huge advantages to running `cpack -G`.  By doing that, you're placing the onus on the dev invoking CPack to make the choice of generator.  Your way, you make it easier for other devs to not have to know about the variety of generators CPack offers.  I guess, like a lot of CMake stuff, there are a few different ways to achieve the same thing.  For me, the decision between them often boils down to "what's going to be easiest for the other devs to use?" or even "what way is the hardest to use wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

CMake tends to use absolute paths except in contexts where there's a strong argument for using relative paths. So I'm pretty sure it's running each regex in `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` against *absolute paths* of files (which should answer your question "*What is it about the ^ (beginning of line) and $ (end of line) that I'm not understanding?*"). Anything that isn't matched by any regex in `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` is *not ignored*.

What you want is probably something like:

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES
  /build/
  /extrafiles/
  /temp/
)
```