# How do I exclude my build directory from CPack's source release?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I just realized that my CPack release's package-version-Source.tar.Z file was 1.4 gigabytes in size. It turns out it's including my entire build directory, including experimental binaries, previous releases, etc., all in each of the tarballs.

How do I exclude my `build` directory (and preferably also my `.vscode` and `.git` directories) from the CPack release? My CPack lines in CMakeLists.txt look like this:

```
include (InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
set (CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE  
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE")
set (CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${Pwr_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set (CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${Pwr_VERSION_MINOR}")
include (CPack)
```

Comment: Looks like you are searching for *CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES* variable, which usage is described in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935748/cpack-ignoring-files-using-regex.

Comment: What are your `INSTALL` commands? Mind you that packaging is supposed to happen from the install tree, not the build tree, as files from the latter are in general not portable.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Running `cd build && cpack --config ./CPackSourceConfig.cmake`, [as stated in the official tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Packaging%20With%20CPack.html), generates an archive with the build directory.  While I agree with your comment, how do I create a source tarball with CPack from the install tree?  Or rather which is the install tree?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same situation, though the size of the resulting source tarbal was less than yours, a couple hundred MB.

My solution was adding a line before

```
include(CPack)
```

In your case, it will look like this

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "build")
include(CPack)
```

Since `"build"` is regex, not only your `build` directory will be excluded, files and directories with names matching `build` will too, for instance, `build-dbg`, `mybuild`etc..

Comment: Obviously, this will not work if the binary directory is changed with `cmake -B <something else>`. Maybe you can use `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/`, but unfortunately, there is no good way to quote this, see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18580.